# Unable to call javascript function globally

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, function, express

I am developing nodejs app with mongoDB. I have written a function which will filter some data from mongodb and store in variable "**docs**". I tried several methods to declare a function globally and tried to access that variable "**docs**" but I couldn't.`

```js
 conn.then(client=> client.db('myprojectone').collection('offlinemessage').find({nameTo:"sd"}).limit(1).toArray(function(err, docs) {
      if(err) { console.error(err) }
       res.send(JSON.stringify(docs))
      console.log(docs);
      return docs;
}))
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Make one helper function which performs all your requirement along with `DB query` and `filter` result and returns that result. Exports this function using `module.exports` like below.

**utils.js** // Helper file

```
const utils = {};

utils.getData = async () => {
    try {
        // ...Your business logic
        return true; // It will be your variable 
    } catch (err) {
        logger.error(err);
        throw err;
    }
};

module.exports = utils;
```

call `utils.getData()` to get your result;

**userController**

```
const utils = require('./helper/utils');

const userController = {};

userController.getData = async () => {
    try {
        const result = await utils.getData();
    } catch (err) {
        logger.error(err);
        throw err;
    }
};

module.exports = userController;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access async function variable outside of function.

Comment: You need to make sync call

Answer (score 0):

**Express.js** Gives simple thing to access global functions

```html
 fnName = function(){ return "hi"; }; // i.e. don't do: var name = function(){ ... };
    console.log(fnName());         // this prints "hi"
    console.log(global.fnName());  // this also prints "hi" - it was assigned to global.
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to create a service js class file, called utils.js and then add in this class that you require globally,

utils.js

```js
export default class Example {
  static getDocs() {
    // Rest of the global method
  }
}
```

And in the place that you require the docs variable, you simply call the method `getDocs()`

```js
import Utils from '<location_to_utils.js>';
console.log(Utils.getDocs());
```